# How to represent hour to hour Highcharts tooltip - Time series?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am new to highcharts. My data is in the format:

```
data : [[1442169000000, 7.36], [1442172600000, 8.67]]
```

and in high charts:

```
tooltip: {
            xDateFormat: dateFormat,
            shared: true

        },
```

Graph:

```
Current input: "%A, %b %d, %Y %l:%M%P"
Current output of tooltip on each point: Monday, Sep 14, 2015 9:00am
Required output of tooltip: Monday, Sep 14, 2015 9:00am -10:00am
```

i.e., I need to show 9.00am to 10am instead of 9am.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: please put your code to fiddle

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=t9feA22Gh1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

working fiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/4xmc0fwv/1/
use this  :

```
           tooltip: {
            xDateFormat: "%A, %b %d, %Y %l:%M%P",
            shared: true,           
                formatter: function () {
                    datex=new Date(this.x);
                    date2= new Date(datex);
                    date2.setHours ( datex.getHours() + 1 );
                    return Highcharts.dateFormat('%A, %b %d, %Y %l:%M%P',
                            datex) +" - "      +Highcharts.dateFormat('%l:%M%P',date2); 
                }

        },
```